# Grouping rake tasks from other gems

Tags: rake

To avoid having to trigger many rake tasks when I want to reinitialize my project I created the following task in `lib/task/twiddle.rake`:

```
task :twiddle => %w(db:drop db:create railties:install:migrations db:migrate db:seed spree_sample:load)
```

Triggering each of these command from the command line works.
However running `rake twiddle` hangs when it reaches `spree_sample:load` with the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `slug' for #<Spree::Product:0x0000000ec9b9f0>
```

Could someone explain why running a set of specific tasks would works on the CLI and not through the rake task? Should I require some libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer's relatively simple actually - Rails loads schema information from the database only when it boots. (You can do something like reset_schema_information to force it to reload)

You generally don't ever do db:migrate followed by db:seed right after because Rails won't reload the app between the migration and the seeding. Therefore, when db:seed runs, it will have no table information. This is why you see different results if you run them individually -- the act of running them individually makes Rails reload itself and fixes the catch-22 of trying work with a schema that is only made available by the previous command.

Also railties:install:migrations makes no sense in your task-- you only run that yourself as the developer 1 time, it creates several migration files (which you check-in to git), and then those files live in your app forever. You don't re-run railties:install:migrations on regular basis, since you've already created those migration files. (You do re-run it when you upgrade spree, but that's a different matter)

Comment: That quite makes sense, thank you. How would you proceed to have rails being reloaded after the `db:migrate` / before the `db:seed`?

Comment: I just replace that list of tasks by `db:reset spree_sample:load` which is the same as `db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:seed spree_sample:load`
It didn't really make sense to do a db:migrate after having recreated the database anyway. Thanks for helping me understand this process.